# JavaScript, CSS, HTML5 editor for Android tablets

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, editor

Can anyone recommend cool JavaScript, CSS, HTML5 editor for Andorid tablet?

iPad has the following cool app

http://panic.com/dietcoda/

However I still prefer Android platform and looking for cool software for it.

Answer (score 1):

I use DroidEdit Pro.. Works perfectly on my Motorola Xoom.

Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidedit.pro&feature=search_result

There is a free version that you could try first too. Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidedit&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hb3IuZHJvaWRlZGl0Il0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the anWriter editor.
Supports HTML, CSS and JavasScript syntax highlihting and autocompletion(and PHP and SQL in the full version).
Full support for hardware keyboards.

[Fre version on the Google Play (with adds)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ansm.anwriter)

[Full version on the Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ansm.anwriter.pro)